# Adding multiple contacts to event through apex

Tags: apex

i want to associate multiple contacts to single event through apex (Adding to whoID), which is possible to UI, but how can i do from the apex?

We can add multiple contacts as event attendees through event relation, similar i want to add multiple contacts with event who id through apex? how can i achieve this?

Comment: got it, we need to check isparent boolean in eventreationship object

Answer (score 1):

You can only have one primary whatId and instead need to create eventRelation which reporesent people or resources for the event.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm